# Ubuntu Server: Don't see my input in terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, console

I have a problem with my Ubuntu server. I start a new remote ssh session (from windows putty or ubuntu client) to my server. After a while (I think it is when I hide the console window), my input is not shown in the console. But when I type for example "ls", I get the listing.

This means that the input was sended, but I don't see it. I can only close the console and start a new ssh session. But the next annoying point is, that when I start a new screen and I have this problem there, it don't go away after reconnecting. I have to restart the screen bash.

Does anyone have an idea whats going wrong? It seems that it is a problem on the server, because I tried with windows and linux with the same result.

thanks
plucked

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This can happen  after a program dies leaving a terminal in an abnormal state.
To fix it temporary you "reset" the terminal with:

```
$ reset
```

Comment: If reset fixes your problem, then you probally are running an application which messes with your terminal settings.

Comment: In the rare cases where the `icrnl` line setting has been disabled, it is advisable to type `Control-J reset Control-J`. (you can ignore the spaces). Return typically sends CR, which is converted to NL on input if *icrnl* is enabled. If it's not, then typing something and pressing Return does not send the command to the shell.

Comment: After running reset, I get this message: 
"reset: unknown terminal type xterm-256color
Terminal type?"

Could you clarify how to handle this?

Answer (score 3):

While @rkthkr's answer worked for me, it has the unfortunate side-effect of changing my terminal window dimensions from what they were - which in some cases, I suppose this may also have been corrupted and also in need of a reset.

With this in mind, I'm using:

```
$ stty sane
```

From `man stty`:

```
   sane   same as cread -ignbrk brkint -inlcr -igncr icrnl  -iutf8  -ixoff
          -iuclc  -ixany  imaxbel opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret
          -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0 isig icanon  iexten  echo
          echoe  echok  -echonl  -noflsh  -xcase  -tostop -echoprt echoctl
          echoke, all special characters to their default values
```

In my particular case, using `pv -c` (pipe viewer) consistently caused my input to go hidden.  For now, I've actually scripted a `stty sane` command after my command that uses `pv -c` to ensure that my terminal remains functional.

Comment: This is happening far too often for me. Is there anything wrong with adding `stty sane` to `PROMPT_COMMAND`?

Answer (score 0):

When you can't see the command that you are typing, can you see the prompt and the cursor?

If not, the next time that happens, try the `clear` command, then try typing something and see if you can see it.

If this helps, then it probably means that your prompt is hidden below the bottom of the window for some reason. Either resize the window or scroll back down (you may have scrolled up in the window buffer somehow).

Comment: I don't see the cursor and clear doesn't help )o:

Comment: Do you see the prompt? Did `clear` clear the screen?